# Why threat modelling and risk planning does not consider the sex of users?

Tags: risk-management, threat-modeling, user-management

Isn't it scientifically proven that men and women have very different psychologies? So that, at least they must have different attitudes towards security policies and guidelines compliance. All of that must have affect on social engineering risks, business continuity, disaster recovery etc.

Comment: No, it is not generally a material factor.

Comment: While there are many interesting questions in this vein, they require data and careful phrasing to avoid being troll bait.  This question as written is too general and likely to end poorly.

Comment: I did not ask your suggestions/warnings regarding the phrasing. Instead of blaming everyone of being troll - you could either give an answer or do not respond at all. Thank you,

Comment: Draif, you may not know it yet, but this site is moderated by its users.  So when someone experienced like @gowenfawr offers you feedback it's a good idea to stop and consider their advice.  I don't believe they were saying you were a troll by asking your question, just that your phrasing might attract more troll answers than if it was worded differently.

Comment: Psychology plays a small role in security, it should only affect social engineering.

Comment: gender is a factor when planning attacks, whether they be social engineering, as rook says, or phishing or other attacks that require getting a user to click...

Comment: ObRef [Who Falls for Phish?](http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/~tdumitra/courses/ENEE759D/Fall13/papers/Sheng10.pdf) although, while they find that women are more likely to fall for phish than men, the clearly consider the secondary effect of differing levels of tech skills as the differentiation, not the primary effects of gender.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any reason why you *shouldn't* use gender as part of a threat model, as long as you can articulate why you think it would make a difference. For most cases, I'd agree with others that it probably wouldn't, but don't let that discourage you.

It might be more interesting to use gender when analyzing attack trees, assigning certain sub-trees a higher likelihood of realization, based on the gender of certain actors.

At the same time, you could be tempted to include other attributes like age, ethnicity, socioeconomic status, phase of the moon, and so on. Threat modeling is hard enough, so be cognizant of the complexity that each attribute you consider adds to the task.